# Using Embeded XSLT in XML File

Tags: xslt

I use  saxon library for java xml converter. 
sample:

```
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltUrl));
transformer.setURIResolver(resolver);
```

and I make convert xml to html using xslt file. but I want to using embedded xslt file in xml file...

my xml file;

```
<cac:Attachment>
    <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject 
           characterSetCode="UTF-8" 
           encodingCode="Base64" 
           filename="xxxx.xslt"
           mimeCode="application/xml">PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZ...
```

How can I get or save as attachment file(xxxx.xslt)  from xml file?

Comment: Can you parse the value from `@filename` attribute and read the file?

Comment: yes, I want to parse filename="xxxx.xslt" from xml file.

Comment: You can retrieve the filename `xxxx.xslt` from the attribute using saxon, and you can use saxon again to parse the file. But these are two distinct steps. There is no function that will fetch the value of the attribute and treat it as a file whose content should be parse. Are you using Java or C?

Comment: @deanosaur I use java.